# Where is my index.html that I already created?

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have a site already. I am moving it to google hosting in firebase. I followed everything when testing it out and was able to get a database working. Just a sample one. So during that process, I set up Firebase and I used a public directory - this is where my question comes in. How do you change public directories for projects? I created three different subdirectories on my macbook, added the files for my previously created sites into public directories of their own, followed all the instructions and once deployed, I only get the google page saying everything is ok and go read the docs now.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you change public directories for projects?

The Firebase CLI reads the`firebase.json` file in your project folder. This `firebase.json` contains a JSON property `public`, which specifies folder that it needs to deploy.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public